# Deserializing from xml file embeded as a resource

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, file, embedded-resource

I have an xml file embedded as a resource. Is there any way to write information of specific type in it and then get the information and put it into a custom object that I made, just like serialization and deserialization with XmlSerializer would work in the case of normal xml files (normal meaning which can be found at a certain location on the computer) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can load your embedded file into a `MemoryStream` and work with it like you would with physical files (where you would use a `FileStream`):

```
Using myEmbeddedXmlFile = New IO.MemoryStream(My.Resources.MyEmbeddedXmlFile)
    ' your code to manipulate the xml file or to deserialize it
End Using
```

Make sure you set the resource's `FileType` to `Binary`.